# Chrome Extension - how to continuously check current tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to have a timer run based on certain URLs and output a message when a limit is reached.  Unfortunately, I have only been able to use tabs.onActivated and tabs.onUpdated in background.js to update my timer.

This means that my timer does not update while in one of the flagged tabs.  If I try to use a while loop in background.js, it does not work.

I added a function call to popup.js that gets an updated time, but that is only called when I have the popup open. Are there any listeners that continuously check the current tab or is there a completely different way to do this that I haven't though about?

Thanks!

popup method:

```
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

function myTimer() {
    var bgPage = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
    var time = bgPage.updateTime();
    document.getElementById("clock").textContent = "TIME: " + time;
    if (chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().limit == -1){
        document.getElementById("limit").textContent = "LIMIT: " + "N/A"
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("limit").textContent = "LIMIT: " + bgPage.updateLimit();
    }
}
```

manifest:

```
"background": {
      "scripts": ["format.js", "background.js"],
      "persistent": true
     },
```

Edit: added in manifest

Comment: The full picture isn't clear so I'll comment on the parts I see. The popup runs only when shown. The background script needs to be declared with `"persistent":true` (or no "persistent" entry at all), otherwise it'll be unloaded after 5 second of inactivity. In such a persistent script you can use setTimeout anywhere. There are no listeners that *check* anything so you would need to invoke the appropriate API explicitly.

Comment: Sorry for not including everything, the listeners in my backgrounds are pretty big.  I added in the alarms API to have them called every second, but that kinda goes against its design. Any suggestions?

Comment: Also, I already had ```persistent=true```, I just needed some sort of continuous check on my tabs